# NextJS helper function is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

I tried making a function in NextJS but when I try to call it, I get an error saying that something is not a function.[image]

Here's the code of the function that I am trying to invoke here

```
'use client'

export const t = (l:string) =>{
    if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
        return window.location
    }
}
```

The problem goes away when I remove "use client" statement but then I cannot use `window` object that I desperately need now

Comment: are you using 'use client' also in the Home component?

Answer (score 0):

Next.js does not support the use of browser-specific objects like window directly in the top-level scope of your module when using server-side rendering (SSR)

The use-client tells Next.js to only include this module in client-side bundles, effectively excluding it from server-side rendering.

However, when you try to call this function on the server-side, window is not defined, hence the error.

to avoid this issue:

```
export const getLocation = () => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        return window.location;
    }
    return null; // or handle the case when window is not available
};
```

Then, wherever you use this function, make sure to handle the case where window might not be defined:

```
// In your component or function
const location = getLocation();
if (location) {
    // Do something with the location object
} else {
    // Handle the case when window is not available
}
```